Does "comédie musicale" apply to all musicals or just as the name suggests to comedies?
For example would you call Les Misérables "une comédie musicale" or would you say "mais non, c'est un drame musical"? Or maybe "une tragédie musicale"?

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Com%C3%A9die_musicale

And a direct entry to Les Misérables.

The French word comédie doesn't necessarily imply a comic performance. Does not have quite the same uses as the English "comedy".

@None: I do not agree with you. We speak of comedies for Molières'plays, and drames ou tragédies for the ones from Racine or Corneille for a reason. I know that we now use comedien for any acteur, but I can remember speaking of tragédiens for actors that were great in tragedies.

@SergeBallesta Not expressing a personal opinion here so you have to disagree with dictionaries.  1st and oldest meaning of Comédie in the TLFi: « Pièce de théâtre, quel que soit le genre auquel elle appartient » —  « 1539 pièce de théâtre ayant pour but de divertir en représentant les travers, les ridicules, des caractères et des moeurs d'une société (opposé à tragédie) (DHLF).

@None: The Nouveau Larousse Encyclopédique, édition 1998 says: 1. Pièce de théatre qui excite le rire... 2. Genre littéraire, cinématographique, etc., qui fait rire ou sourire.... In a more detailed article, I find (emphasize mine): Dans la mesure ou le terme ne désigne pas comme souvent au XVII° siècle toute pièce de théatre sans distinction de genre ... sa finalité est de déclencher le rire chez le spectateur. My understanding is that comédie used to be used for any play, but in now used where a comic performance is involved.

@SergeBallesta Now you agree with me. So in comédie musicale comédie doesn't imply a comic performance, which any bilingual dictionary would told the OP.

@None: What I mean is that when used alone (nowadays), comédie implies some comic effects. But when used in comédie musicale or comédie dramatique no comic performance is to be expected.
